# How to test if The Digital Deluxe Edition is active in Baldur's Gate 3?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I bought The Digital Deluxe Edition with the game. Then, I refunded the game, but not The Digital Deluxe Edition - it was my silent protest against it not working properly on SteamDeck despite its "✔️Verified" status. Now I re-bought the game, I have it installed with the "The Digital Deluxe Edition" as DLC, but Larian launcher still prompts me to buy "The Digital Deluxe Edition Upgrade".

So, how can I verify in the game if it is installed and available? Where should I find the content it promises? I'm at the beginning of Act One, if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are about to throw your die at any moment, click on the button in the bottom-left corner of the screen that says "Customize dice" when hovered.

Then if you have the *Dragonflame Red* die in your list it means that you have the Deluxe Edition installed because that's an exclusive dice skin.

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks! Will try as soon as possible :)